# Reset printing to default on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, printing, group-policy

Due to an issue we are experiencing with Windows 10 and printing, whereby a computer GPO does not apply group policy deployed printers every time, I would like to investigate resetting the printing system completely to factory settings.

I know there are hundreds of registry entries, drivers and many many different possible setups for this so I will try and explain the setup a bit more.

- The users which are affected are users logging in with mandatory profiles
- All files are removed on log off for the user
- Sometimes, manually running a printer spooler restart shows the printers
- Sometimes, a 0x57 error occurs
- Point and print restrictions are in effect
- We have Dell and Sharp printers

I have tried lookback processing in merge mode with printers deployed to users within the computer OU.
I have tried using printer isolation mode
I have tried modifying some registry entries, for example, clearing the client rendering registry key and adding an attribute to one of the printer drivers

I am not the only person having trouble out here:
http://www.edugeek.net/forums/windows-10/191185-disappearing-printers-16.html
http://www.edugeek.net/forums/windows-10/210333-windows-10-printing-issues-gpo-deployment-3.html
https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/9xi3cd/windows_10_network_printers_disappearing/
https://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/windows-10-1803-gpo-printers-inconsistent.250182/

I have tried every solution so far and have not got anything concrete. Its always still intermittent. We have 10 gig links from the switches to our print server and they are accessible by the users and from the machines.

Any ideas? Is there a way I can reset the printing system to default as the issue only seems to occur after a few days from being built? Our systems are built using WIM files deployed using SCCM and have no issues with this system.

Is there some kind of corruption going on in the registry? The setup worked perfectly with Windows 7.

Comment: Try `net stop spooler && del /F /S /Q %systemroot%\System32\spool\PRINTERS\* && net start spooler` as local administrator.

Comment: that does the spooler. That does not clear anything else in the printing system. I also have to point out that we are not installing to the machine as they are server GPO deployed printers i.e. C:\Windows\System32\spool\SERVERS which I can obviously clear in the same manner but this does not help the process

Comment: Read [Microsoft Fixit for Printing](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Ask-The-Performance-Team/Microsoft-Fixit-for-Printing/ba-p/375025). Of course it is applied to ancient versions, not to Windows 10, but maybe...

Comment: I'll give it a go, obviously manually as all the fixits are hidden away somewhere in microsofts database and not linked any more.

Comment: So I ended up reworking group policy to push printers to user groups based on where the computer is. It was a nightmare getting it right but now GPO sorts it all out for me.